# Is there a way to list the CloudWatch log groups which are created 6 months ago

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I wanted to list the CloudWatch log groups which are created 6 months back. we have 5000+ log groups in AWS Account.
is there a way to list the log groups through aws cli or any script?

Comment: Get all log groups, filter out the ones you are interested in.

Answer (score 0):

```
import boto3
import datetime

t_minus_6_months = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=180)

logs_client = boto3.client('logs')

paginator = logs_client.get_paginator('describe_log_groups')

for page in paginator.paginate():
    for group in page['logGroups']:
        if group['creationTime'] >= t_minus_6_months:
            print(group['logGroupName'])
```

Since you said you have more than 5000 log groups, you have to use a paginator. If a log group was created in any period between today and t-6 months, the log group name will be printed.

[Doc to used boto3 function.](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/logs.html#CloudWatchLogs.Client.describe_log_groups)